# Unselectable content/text within an HTML table

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<table class="code-table hljs">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="code-row">
      <td class="line-number unselectable">1</td>
      <td class="code-col">one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="code-row">
      <td class="line-number unselectable">2</td>
      <td class="code-col">two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="code-row">
      <td class="line-number unselectable">3</td>
      <td class="code-col">three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The relevant css:

```
.unselectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

In both Firefox and Chrome if I select all (ctrl-a), what I expect to happen, only "one", "two", and "three" are selected and not the line numbers, happens. However, when I paste what's in the clipboard I get differing results:

Chrome output:

```
one
2 two
3 three
```

Firefox output:

```
one

two

three
```

So Chrome is copying every unselectable line except the first, and firefox is putting in an extra line where there shouldn't be one.

Current Chrome version is Version 54.0.2840.71 m and current firefox version is 49.0.2 (Both are able to use `user-select: none;` according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=user-select-none

Is a css solution to this currently possible?

**Edit**
Please note that the table I'm receiving is being rendered by another library and I can really only manipulate the classes.

Comment: Note that the [specification is still in Working Draft status](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-4/#content-selection), but states: *This specification makes no normative requirement about the behavior of the clipboard.* You're seeing what happens when browsers don't have a standard telling them how to behave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rounin almost had it. Here's a modified version of what he made. It will show highlighting the 1-3 but it wont copy.

```css
.unselectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
 }


 .code-table {
 counter-reset: code-table;
 }

 .code-table tr td:nth-of-type(2)::before {
 counter-increment: code-table;
 content: counter(code-table) '  \00a0\00a0';
 }
```

```html
<table class="code-table hljs">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="code-row">
      <td class="line-number unselectable">1</td>
      <td class="code-col">one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="code-row">
      <td class="line-number unselectable">2</td>
      <td class="code-col">two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="code-row">
      <td class="line-number unselectable">3</td>
      <td class="code-col">three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It only looks like it highlights them in chrome, it won't copy.

Comment: You could also do it easily in javascript. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Last thing i promise, the '\00a0\00a0' are just spaces, it was bothering me that the digit numbers were close to their text counterparts.

Comment: Thanks Branded, I will see if I can implement this as well. Have upvoted and will leave open for a few more answers before I accept.

Comment: Sounds good, if you need anything else or don't understand something feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

> Is a css solution to this currently possible?

An HTML solution to this is possible:

```html
<ol>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: the line numbers still need to appear to the left of the content that's being selected.

Comment: Yes - and they do. I have moved the code into a snippet, so you can see.

Comment: Hah, of course. Unfortunately, the HTML table is being rendered by another library, and I only have control over the classes. But upvoted and I'll add that note to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first column of `.code-table` with

```
visibility: collapse;
```

You can then deploy a `::before` pseudo-element containing a CSS Counter in the second column of `.code-table` to solve this issue:

```css
.code-table {
counter-reset: code-table;
}

.code-table tr td:nth-of-type(1) {
visibility: collapse;
}

.code-table tr td:nth-of-type(2)::before {
counter-increment: code-table;
content: counter(code-table) ': ';
}
```

```html
<table class="code-table hljs">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="code-row">
      <td class="line-number unselectable">1</td>
      <td class="code-col">one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="code-row">
      <td class="line-number unselectable">2</td>
      <td class="code-col">two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="code-row">
      <td class="line-number unselectable">3</td>
      <td class="code-col">three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Cracked it with: `visibility: collapse;` !

Comment: On the other hand... in this March 2013 guest post on CSS-Tricks (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/visibility/) Sara Cope inspects the inconsistent browser handling of `visibility: collapse;` and warns: **don't use this ever**.